# Convert asp.net c# 2003 master+pages to fixed menu panel page and loading aspx pages like a partial page with server render (without calling master)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, master-pages, visual-studio-2003

In a web application `asp.net c# 2003`  project that consists of **master page** and other **pages **as follows:

Currently the project is using a **home page** full of icons that user click one and then goes to the related page.
To come back user has to click on home link, or use bread crumbs links.

Now I want to change it so that in master page a **fixed panel** show all menus, grouped, and rest space on master page to be used for a Place Holder (like a div) and be filled with dynamic selected **htmls **codes for the pages that user clicked.

I have changed UI so that menu is filled and ready to use, when user click on any menu:

There is 2 possibility:

1- Using Post back, page is sent back to server, then master page, menus and requested page render and result come back to use.

2- A javascript function is called to load requested aspx page from the server.

The first one works fine.

But as the second one is preferred, I tried it and faced problems.

**Using Javascript**

When calling an asp.net page, server renders the page and master page together and send result back to user, while on my page I have master page and menus and I just needed the requested page to be rendered on server ( since it contains language resources and jobs to be done ) and the result as html come back and inject to a div on page.

**Question:**
I have tried all of these:

1- How to call an aspx page and force server to ignore master page and send back just rendered page html?

2- Or how to call server and use a **ascx user control** to run and render aspx page and send resulted html back?

3- Or how to call a **ashx ** page and code it to call the aspx page to render without master page?

I have tried all of them and failed, page come back without master page but it is not rendered or page and master pare rendered together.

Now I use an empty master page and the project is working, but in middle of my page there is another `html>body>` element that is very unpleasant.

Conversion or upgrade is not possible.

**Jquery calling page:**

```
function setPartialPage(address){
    //var url = Host + '/Default.ashx';
    var url = Host + address.replace('~', '');
    console.log(url);
    
    // Ajax that call server - Works fine.
    getResult('{"IdFunction":"' + address + '"}',
        url,
        showResult
    );
}
function showResult(data) {
    if (data === "undefined" || data === "404" || data === "404," || data.length === 0) {
        showMessage(data.replace('404,', '').replace('404', ''), 'red', 'Page not loaded!');
    } else {
        $("#app").html(data)
    }
}
```

**Default.ashx.cs file:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Trade
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class Default : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            var masirPage = context.Request.Form["IdFunction"] as string;
            context.Response.WriteFile(masirPage);
            //context.Response.WriteFile(masirPage.Replace(".aspx", ".ascx"));
            //context.Response.WriteFile("~/App_Main/User/Request/Tavoni/Default.ascx");
        }
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WHEN you create a aspx web page, YOU THE DEVELOPER make the choice if that page is to be part of a master page or not (this choice occures at create page time). . Any existing page that built with master page will thus load master page. Such pages can't just out of the blue be loaded without the master page (you have to create a new web page - copy the content from older page). So, you want to re-create that page - and use VS to do this for you.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Have you tried it by yourself? Seems wrong comment. Please be more accurate. I tested and seems that in .NET it is not possible to call a page without being wrapped inside a html structure or connecting to a master page.

Comment: Content controls are allowed only in content page that references a master page.

Comment: Correct. If you don't want the master page, then you have to remove the content control, and move that markup into the page's form area, which it will NOW require. I suggest creating a new aspx page without a master page if you going to convert such web pages - and that's a lot of work.  See my post below - but the answer is you can't have someone's else's work change how it works unless YOU the developer decide to re-design those web pages. See , my post below